# Odd telnet data separation when using sock.send

Tags: c#

I'm creating a telnet program in C#, and I'm running into a strange occurrence: when I send keystrokes from the client they are only registered when I press return in this example:

```
public void OnRecievedData( IAsyncResult ar )
{
        SocketGameClient client = (SocketGameClient)ar.AsyncState;
        byte [] aryRet = client.GetRecievedData( ar );

        // If no data was recieved then the connection is probably dead
        if( aryRet.Length < 1 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "Client {0}, disconnected", client.Sock.RemoteEndPoint );
            client.Sock.Close();
            m_aryClients.Remove( client );                      
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(aryRet).Trim());

        foreach (SocketGameClient clientSend in m_aryClients) 
        {
              //clientSend.Sock.Send(aryRet);
        }

        client.SetupRecieveCallback( this );
}
```

But if I remove the comment in the `foreach` loop it will send each and every keystroke separately.

I just don't see how that is happening. I would like to know why it works that way.

Comment: im using
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(aryRet).Trim());
to figure out what data its receiving and in the intital example i can send for example 

hello<return>

and my servers console will echo hello

but after i remove that comment it will echo each character seperatly as i type it

Comment: That's not really for you to know because it's implementation details below the application level that don't concern you. At the application level, you just need to know that TCP will get all the of the data to you in the correct order or let you know that it can't. You'll usually have to allow for reassembling the messages, but they'll all be there in the correct order.

Comment: its just that i need to know when someone has pressed a key regardless of weather or not i send something back to the client, is there a way to do this because my callback doesn't get called for each key unless im sending data back